# The GRANT command does not work properly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, sql-grant

I am using AWS AuroraDB.

I tried to give `SELECT` permission to the user by entering like this.

```
USER mysql;
GRANT SELECT ON 'sample'.'sample_table' TO 'user'@'111.11.%.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I tried this command, 'sample'.'sample_table' was not shown. But other permissions are visible.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'111.11.%.%'
```

please help me. thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `TO` after object name. Other than that, the first command should be `USE db_name`. The correct syntax should be like this:

```
USE db_name;
GRANT SELECT ON 'sample'.'sample_table' TO 'user'@'111.11.%.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

More information look at [their documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html).